# How I can validate my form with existing method written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have write a validator.js which contain the code for validate rules by regex.

Here is the code I got on the page

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("corePhoneUS", coreFieldValidator.phoneUS, "Please enter a 10 digit phone number. Ex: 801-555-1212");
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("coreZipUS", coreFieldValidator.zipUS, "Please enter a 5 or 9 digit zip code. Ex: 84045, or 84045-1234");
```

Now I have html form that I want to validate. $("#contactForm").validate() is not working. I have seen no error.

Do someone know how to apply existing method in validate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have applied the validation rules to some input fields on the form:

```
$('#contactForm').validate({
    rules: {
        someInputElementName: {
            corePhoneUS: true
        },
        someOtherInputElementName: {
            coreZipUS: true
        }
    }
});
```